# Comma doesnt work on Samsung Android Keyboard with Flutter

Tags: flutter, samsung-mobile

My Samsung Galaxy Tab s4 (SM-T830) keyboard key is stuck when I try to press it. Although I'm using a `TextFormField` of type number with a keyboardType of `TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)` it doesn't work.

[image]